# Updating DateTime in access through C#. Data mismatch

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, ms-access

I have a date and time loaded into a textbox for editing, but I need to store it as a datetime in my access database not a string and cannot remember or find the syntax to parse it in my SQL parameters... here is my code anyway...

```
string strSql = "UPDATE OCR SET OCR = @OCR, [OCR Title] = @OCRTitle, DeadlineDate = @DeadlineDate;";

using (OleDbConnection newConn = new OleDbConnection(strProvider))
{
      using (OleDbCommand dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, newConn))
      {
           dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OCRTitle", textBox6.Text);
           dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OCR", textBox5.Text);
           dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeadlineDate", textBox7.Text);

           newConn.Open();
           dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
 }
```

Comment: I don't believe Access supports named parameters, so you need to provide positional parameters in the same order as they appear in the query (i.e. your @OCR parameter should be before the @OCRTitle parameter).  Also check the types of all your columns, not only `@DeadlineDate` as suggested by Jon Skeet, and post the full details of the exception you're getting.  It's also unusual to use an UPDATE statement without a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're specifying a string as the deadline date value. You should specify a `DateTime` instead.

You can use `DateTime.Parse` (or `DateTime.ParseExact`, or `DateTime.TryParseExact`) to parse the text representation if you really have to - but it would be better to use a date-based control to start with, rather than having a text representation *at all*.

(It's not clear what sort of application this is - WinForms, ASP.NET etc - but most GUIs have some sort of date picker these days.)

EDIT: Additionally, you need to change the order in which you add the parameters to the command such that it matches the order in which the parameters are used in the SQL statement. These are effectively positional parameters - the names are ignored. It would probably be clearer to use `?` than named parameters in the SQL.

Comment: Still saying mismatch error :S.. using  dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeadlineDate", DateTime.Parse(textBox7.Text));

Comment: @user3086447: Are you sure that's the parameter which is failing? What are the types of `OCR` and `OCRTitle` in your database? Are you sure the type of `DeadlineDate` is `DateTime`?

Comment: Yes I have other statements in my code that work fine with the OCR and OCR Title. My Access column is also set to Date/Time yes.

Comment: @user3086447: Then I'd really expect it to be okay. Do you have *any* other information beyond "mismatch error"? I note that you're adding the parameters in a different order to the order in the update statement - might that be a problem? Also, you're trying to update *all* rows... is that deliberate?

Comment: Yes, I may have an error in my DB I will update when I have had a look.

Comment: The OCR Field in my DB is text but I am inserting a number, not sure if this matters. I tried changing to number but everything just went insanely wrong.

Comment: @user3086447: You're not really inserting a number - you're specifying a string. That may happen to be a string representation of a number, but it's still a string. You should still look at the other bits of my comment though, about ordering and updating all the rows.

Comment: Ok I have sorted the order, that worked. But its changing all records, so I inserted a where statement but not sure what to include in the WHERE statement because I am selecting a cell value from datagridview.

Comment: @user3086447: Well you should have something to identify which row to update. Was changing the order enough to fix it (along with using DateTime)? If so, I'll edit my answer to include that.